# Access violation when affecting a value to variable?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

The code below is written in unit2 ( form2), it calls the values entered in the email and password boxes ( in form1 ), yesterday the code was working perfectly, i made some changes and now : This code doesn't work, it raises an Access Violation error when i click the Button COMMENCER:

```
  procedure TForm2.Btn_commencerClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin

  email := form1.ed_Email.Text;// <----- LOOK HERE 
  password := form1.Ed_typedpass.Text; // <-----AND HERE
  MD5 := GetMD5;
  MD5.Init;
  MD5.Update(TByteDynArray(RawByteString(password)), Length(password));
  password := LowerCase(MD5.AsString);

  etc.......
```

But this code works :

```
 email := 'myemail@yahoo.com';
 password := 'mypass'; 
 MD5 := GetMD5;
 MD5.Init;
 etc etc......
```

The question :

Why ?

Comment: where the Access violation ocurs in your code?

Comment: in this line:      email := form1.ed_Email.Text;

EAccess Violation at address 0067A868 ( read of address 0000038C )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you creating your form1 object? Sounds like it haven't initialized before you access it and therefore you get AV.

Your second code works, because you don't have to initialize string variables before accessing or assigning values to them and you are assigning them directly, not through the form1 variable.

But breakpoint to `email := form1.ed_Email.Text;` and look if form1 is `nil` or not.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to create the form1 (as i think its available form in your case)..and you may have closed and freed the form so, your

```
  email := form1.ed_Email.Text;
```

is giving AV, as form1 doesnt exist(as its freed now) ,so u cannot have the **ed_Email.Text** value.

make sure your not closing the form1 (freeing) before pressing **Btn_commencer**

Answer (score 1):

You can always check if the form has been created first to avoid access violations.

if assigned(Form1) then
begin
   // assignments
end;

Comment: +1, this is a good way to check for the available forms if they are created or not..
@Rafik but make sure you are using the Form1 variable which is not local to your procedure but your actual form1 name (global)